# Get back Memory from java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, serversocket

in my java program i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when i try to run it.

The program uses ServerSocket and Socket to receive packets from a client program, which uses Socket too. I previously was using treads for the server but now the program contains only main and a receiver function.

here is the source code:

```
public class TCPEmpfang {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TCPEmpfang().startTCPEmpfang();
    }

    private void startTCPEmpfang() {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4712)) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
            while (true) {
                    acceptConnection(serverSocket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void acceptConnection(ServerSocket servSocket) {
        final long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sum = 0;
        try (Socket s = servSocket.accept()) {
            System.out.println("NEU");
            s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            try (InputStream input = s.getInputStream();
                 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(input)) {
                while (true) {
                    int dataSize = dis.readInt();
                    byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
                    dis.readFully(data);
                    sum += dataSize;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
        final double goodPut = (double) sum / timeDiff * 8 / 1000;

        System.out.println("The goodput was: " + goodPut + " kbit/s");

        writeResults(goodPut);
    }
```

My question is why this Exception occurs in this program? And I am interested in how i know if there is memory leak and whether there can be a memory leak in intelliJ (JetBrains) at all.

I have read a lot about how to expand the heap, but I am not interested in that.

thanks for your answers :)

Comment: this is what the error message looks like:
```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at abgabe6.TCPEmpfang.acceptConnection(TCPEmpfang.java:40)
 at abgabe6.TCPEmpfang.startTCPEmpfang(TCPEmpfang.java:23)
 at abgabe6.TCPEmpfang.main(TCPEmpfang.java:16)
```

Comment: What is an expected value for `dataSize` - try allocating `data` before entering loop (to some reasonable length) and if `dataSize` is bigger than current length of `data` then grow `data` by 2x for example.  But the point is do not reallocate every iteration and re-use current allocation.

Comment: thx Andy, according to your hint I looked into `dataSize` and its value was 1633771873 so that probably causes the exception.